# How do I change my Destiny 2 server on Steam?

Tags: destiny-2

I recently picked up Destiny 2 again after essentially ignoring it since it was given away for free on Battle.net. I completed the Steam transfer, did some crossplay account linking and logged into the game.

Turns out, that because my Steam region is set to Belgium (I live in Flanders), the game defaults me to a French server. I don't speak good enough French to play on a French server, so I'm wondering: is it possible to switch servers I play on so I can play on an English server?

Comment: While the game was on battle.net there were only 3 locations, US , Europe and Asia. So I would find it weird that they split up in multiple servers more. How do you know you are on a french server? Is it because your game is in French? Or are people speaking French because that is a possibility too, French people are playing on the same server.

Comment: @Lyrion I had multiple people speaking French, and chat messages about people entering local chat were also in French. The rest of my game was in English.

Comment: Hmm I still think you were unlucky and the place just filled up with French people, because I'm Belgian as well and there are some french people yeah, but that is because they play on the same server.